# parsing ajax response html/xml with lxml changes < > charcters to

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I`m trying to parse in Python a webpage, a ajax response which basically looks like this
xml:

```
<table class="tab02">
    <tr>
        <th>Skrót</th>
        <th>Pełna nazwa</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><a href="http://www.gpw.pl/karta_spolki/PLATAL000046/">1AT</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.gpw.pl/karta_spolki/PLATAL000046/">ATAL SPÓŁKA AKCYJNA</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Link: http://www.gpw.pl/ajaxindex.php?action=GPWCompanySearch&start=listForLetter&letter=A&listTemplateName=GPWCompanySearch%2FajaxList_PL

If I provide this code in python file as variable with use of simple code & lxml library (see below) I successfully parse everything, and whole result is well formated:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
print etree.tounicode(root) # print etree.tostring(root)
```

**Problem happens while parsing data from webpage (see example code below)**

```
magical_parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8', recover=True)
root = etree.parse(link2page, magical_parser)
print etree.tounicode(root)
```

**In result all  characters < > from table are changed to < and >**

```
<response>
<html>
&lt;table class="tab02"&gt;
    &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;th&gt;Skrót&lt;/th&gt;
        &lt;th&gt;Pełna nazwa&lt;/th&gt;
    &lt;/tr&gt;
etc.
```

I`ve tried also with first treating link with urlib, with parsing it as html but i fail all the time. Can anyone provide me a hint please?